# which color is used to select the option in next js?

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js

[image: 1]

I am creating next.js project and this is first time i see this option .

I don't know which one is selected ?

I want to create next js for javascript .

not typescript.

I just want to know which one is selected one so i can continue

blue / white is selected one ?

Comment: How about you try them both and find out? :D My guess is green. In UI design, green is often used for affirmative things, especially when comared to white, which is often used as a neutral colour.

Answer (score 0):

It is green. Just use the LEFT Arrow to select *No* and proceed.

[image]